# Why does `Pattern.compile("(?:\u00e9)",Pattern.CANON_EQ)` throw?

Tags: java, unicode

There's no limitation on the regular expression compiled with the `Pattern.CANON_EQ`. However

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\u00e9)",Pattern.CANON_EQ);
```

throws an exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 11
((?:é)|é)|e)́)
       ^
```

Note that the pattern is the normalized string. It looks like a bug in JRE, but I can't find such a bug in the issue tracker.

Comment: I get a slightly different error, the unmatched closing ')' is near index 13 here, `(?:(?:e)|é)|e))`, the penultimate ')' is indicated. It doesn't throw with two extra opening '(' or with an ASCII char between `\u00e9` and the ')'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4867170

Comment: Oh boy. It's a bug from 2003! It is acceptable to have such bugs, but it must be clearly indicated in the documentation!

Comment: The funny thing is that this bug is duplicated in IBM JDK